# Problem publishing with Shotwell

Tags: shotwell

I had this problems while trying to publish photos using Shotwell:

1. **Problem with facebook account:**  It duplicates the pictures (about 100 duplicates for every picture)
   This error also consumes time (4 hours for 10 pictures)
2. **Problem with Picasa account:**  It throws this error: `code 400 Bad Request`

Comment: I suspect the public API for both Facebook and Picasa might have changed and Shotwell has fallen behind, but let's wait for an informed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error with Picasa has an explanation [here](https://picasa.google.com/)

"We’ve decided to retire Picasa in order to focus on a single photo service in Google Photos"